# Does sklearn use pandas index as a feature?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I'm passing a pandas DataFrame containing various features to sklearn and I do not want the estimator to use the dataframe index as one of the features.  Does sklearn use the index as one of the features?

```
df_features = pd.DataFrame(columns=["feat1", "feat2", "target"])
# Populate the dataframe (not shown here)
y = df_features["target"]
X = df_features.drop(columns=["target"])

estimator = RandomForestClassifier()
estimator.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: No it does not, it takes the array underneath the dataframe as your input. You can check this by `print(X.to_numpy())`

Comment: Thank you @Erfan.  Would you happen to know where this happens in the scikit-learn source code?  I searched the code for "to_numpy" and did not find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `sklearn` doesn't use the index as one of your feature. It essentially happens [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L288), when you call the fit method the `check_array` function will be applied. And now if you dig deep into the `check_array` [function](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L585), you can find that you are converting your input into array using `np.array` function which essentially strips the indices from your dataframe as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 
df  

    Name    Age
0   tom     10
1   nick    15
2   juli    14

np.array(df)
array([['tom', 10],
       ['nick', 15],
       ['juli', 14]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to the function. I think the actual conversion is in the np.asarray() function here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/4b0ddeeac9054b98df98705f2bfc79350903130c/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L514